# Storing JSON data in WebSQL server

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, web-sql, intel-xdk

I'm trying to load my JSON data into a webSQL server using .getJSON() and .each to itterate through the records in my database.

```
function createDB(){
var db = openDatabase('Json', '1.0', 'local version of Json db', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE categorie (categorie_id INTEGER, cat_naam TEXT)');
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/Json/welcome/categorie", function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index) {
            console.log(data[index].categorie_id);
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO categorie (categorie_id, cat_naam) VALUES (?,?)', [data[index].categorie_id, data[index].cat_naam]);
        });
    });
});
```

}

But after the id gets writen into the log the javascripts stops running.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, according to some documentation and tutorials I've read I should be doing the syntax allright, but maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm using those 2 functions(.getJson and .each) in conjunction with the transactions.

Also this application is inside of an Intel XDK project using AppFramwork and Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are attempting to perform multiple DB operations synchronously. The DB API works asynchronously, so you need to use callbacks to ensure the previous operation has completed before starting the next one. I would try to do it something like this:

```
function createDB(){
var db = openDatabase('Json', '1.0', 'local version of Json db', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var jsonData;

db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE categorie (categorie_id INTEGER, cat_naam TEXT)', [], getJson);
});

function getJson(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/Json/welcome/categorie", function(data){
        jsonData = data;
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            doInsert(function(){
                console.log("DB inserts complete");
            }, tx);
        });
    });
}

function doInsert(onSuccess, tx){
    if(jsonData.length > 0){
        var data = jsonData.shift();
        console.log(data.categorie_id);
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO categorie (categorie_id, cat_naam) VALUES (?,?)', [data.categorie_id, data.cat_naam], doInsert.bind(this, onSuccess));
    }else{
        onSuccess();
    }
}
```